# how to read a json file in subprocess and use it in subprocess.call in a python code?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, subprocess, pipe

```
import subprocess

json=os.startfile("inputs.json")
json = "C:\Users\Onion1\inputs.json"

subprocess.call([json])
```

tried above methods but couldn't able to open and call in subprocess.

with open("C:\Users\O\ss.txt") as out:
     subprocess.Popen("ls",stdout=out)

Comment: Do you want to read json file and execute commnads from it?

Comment: read a json file and use iti in subprocess

Comment: read Json file as normal text file and parse it and pass its content to subprocess call. Can you please show the Json file you want to read

Comment: `{"sender": "AB", "body": "Trade order wall movement quite with want large. Store whose magazine ability so interest artist. Owner federal west.\nIt situation take kid money structure. Throughout may whose much or training", "id2": "2119739392053", "id": "111", "device_id": "9878"} `   sample json contains 1000 jsons of same format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read file as follows, btw this is not the only way to read file.

```
>>> filename = "inputs.json"
>>> 
>>> fd = open("inputs.json")
>>> json_content = fd.read()
>>> 
>>> fd.close()
>>> 
>>> print(json_content)
{"sender": "AB", "body": "Trade order wall movement quite with want large. Store whose magazine ability so interest artist. Owner federal west.\nIt situation take kid money structure. Throughout may whose much or training", "id2": "2119739392053", "id": "111", "device_id": "9878"}

>>> 
>>>
```

Calling `ls -l` using subprocess

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> 
>>> subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 admin-pc admin-pc 4096 May  7 16:14 cJSON_Test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin-pc admin-pc    0 May 10 10:51 inputs.json
0
>>>
```

Since I am unaware of what you what process you want to execute using subprocess, so I used `ls -l` as an example. Also i'm not clear about whether you want to pass json file content to process or json filename.

Read more about subprocess [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: is there a limit of 1024 count or 2048 count??. big json file is not able to sent subprocess call

Comment: are you passing the json file content to subprocess.call?